# How to define the indentations in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops

This is an example how my directory looks like:

```
> SSSRRR2.bam               SSSRRR24.bam     
> 
> SSSRRR2.bam.bai           SSSRRR24.bam.bai
> 
> SSSRRR2.split.bam         SSSRRR24.split.bam
> 
> SSSRRR2.ump.fastq         SSSRRR24.ump.fastq
```

The only files I need are `.split.bam` and `.bam` files for each ID in order to apply subprocess.check_output. This is the python script I made:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess


if __name__=='__main__':
    path = os.getcwd()
    dir_files = os.listdir(path)
    pair_reads = {}


    for file in sorted(dir_files):
        if file.endswith(".split.bam"):
            ID_1 = file.split(".")[0]
            file1 = file

        if file.endswith(".bam") and not file.endswith(".split.bam") and not file.endswith(".bam.bai"):
            ID_2 = file.split(".")[0]
            file2 = file

        if ID_1 == ID_2:
             pair_reads[file1] = file2

    for key, value in pair_reads.items():
#        print(key)
        name = key.split(".")[0]
        subprocess.check_output("tepid-discover -k -d -i --strict -D -p 36 -n " + name + " -c " + key + " s " + value, shell  = True)
```

However, my problem is the indentation when I apply the loops. If each block of `if` is independent to each other how can I introduce a connection to both, for instance in this block:

```
if ID_1 == ID_2:
    pair_reads[file1] = file2
```

This is the error I got:

```
if ID_1 == ID_2:
NameError: name 'ID_1' is not defined
```

Additionaly, I am using python2 because the program works with python2.
Thank you in advance for your help. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: If blocks aren't *independent of each other*, Python doesn't have block scope. However, ID_1 is **not defined** if it is not the case that `file.endswith(".split.bam")`. So, when you try to use the variable that you only define in that block, it will error because it isn't defined. In fact, the way you've written these conditions, this will never work, since the first condition is mutually exclusive with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one iteration of your loop, only one of `ID_1` and `ID_2` can be defined, because it only looks at one file at a time and the two conditions are mutually exclusive.

There are two simple fixes to that problem: you could give `ID_1` and `ID_2` default values, or you could add another condition before checking that they are the same (e.g. "if both IDs were defined *and* they are the same").

However, this may not make your program work, because `os.listdir` might list the files in a different order than you are expecting.

The easiest solution might be to just look only the `.split.bam` files *or* the `.bam` files, and construct the other yourself.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir(path):
    # separate the last two file extensions from the base name
    basename, *extensions = file.rsplit(os.extsep, 2)
    if extensions == ['split', 'bam'] and basename:
        # found basename.split.bam
        bamfile = basename + '.bam'
        if os.path.exists(bamfile):
            # use basename, bamfile, and file however you want
            subprocess.check_output(...)
```

This finds every `.split.bam` file, and checks if the corresponding `.bam` file exists before running the last line.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. After checking your code, I was wondering how I can name:   extensions == ['split', 'bam'] and basename. What I did is:                              if extensions == ['split', 'bam'] and basename:
            split_bamfile = basename + ".split.bam"
            bamfile = basename + '.bam'
            if os.path.exists(bamfile):
                subprocess.check_output(" tepid-discover" + bamfile  + " -n " + basename + " -c " + bamfile + " -s " + split_bamfile, shell =True)

Comment: After only printing split_bamfile and bamfile, the basename precisely fitted for both of them. Therefore I think the naming worked.                      SRR4209953.split.bam : SRR4209953.bam
SRR4210047.split.bam : SRR4210047.bam

Comment: `file` should already be the `.split.bam` file; `basename` is just the path minus two extensions, so if you give it `"dir/id.split.bam"`, then `basename == "dir/id"`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with indentation. Your program doesn't run the first if statement. I don't know what you want to do, but you can put that comparison nested in something like

```
try: 
    ID_1 and ID_2
except:
    print("qwe")
```